# What is the purpose for CsQuery to render CQ object to html string with Environment.NewLine?

Tags: c#, csquery

I'm using CsQuery library (similar to HtmlAgilityPack) for html processing:

Html string -> CQ dom -> (.. manipulations ..) -> Manipulated CQ dom -> Html string.

The output string needs to be stored in the database, but it's full with "\n" characters (I'm on windows). I'm removing those (creating a whole new string without them) before inserting to the database.

What is the purpose of rendering the CQ dom object to html string if the output is not 100% html string?

Can I render without the "\n" characters ?

Answer (score 0):

It would been helpful if you had posted the code. I think the Render() method would worked.